# Address already in use error when Apache Felix starts

Tags: linux, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I deleted the directory felix-cache. When I started again the Felix framework I get this error:

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Another process is still running using the specific port. Check remaining processes using `ps -ef | grep java` and kill it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be launching the JVM in remote debugging mode, but there is another JVM running that is *also* in remote debug mode using the same port number. You cannot share the port number between multiple processes. If you need to debug two Java programs simultaneously then you will have to configure them to use different ports.